# php class can't debug any error, how to use php classes , OOP PHP not working, cURL JSON API

Tags: php, class, curl

The question was actually a silly issue handling the authentication(the key was wrong) so basically that's why I didn't receive any response . thank you and sorry for all the trouble . I would vote to delete the question.

Comment: @Jan1337z I have error_reporting("E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE") as can be seen in the code. Isn't that enough ?

Comment: @Jan1337z in php.ini i have set ; display_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) takes PHP constants E_ALL, etc. To turn on errors, use:

`error_reporting(E_ALL)`, not `"E_ALL"`

Also, you are setting all the options on $ch, which should be a reference returned from `curl_init()`. Since this is missing, nothing is happening. If you modify the code to the following, you should at least see some result.

```
public function theCurl($url, $postFields){
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    ...
```

Also, as mentioned in another answer, you need to create a `new` dnsClass.

```
$c = new dnsClass();
$c->createZone($domain);
print_r($c);
```

Comment: thanks a lot ... indeed it seems I forgot to define $ch .. however it still behaves the same( no response,  no error). any idea what should I set to see the errors or at least why is still not working. It's quite hard to find why is not working without error report .

Comment: I have amended the answer to explain why error_reporting was not working as expected, and also to correct an error regarding your creation of the dnsClass

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I set error_reporting(E_ALL) and also added the resource $ch = curl_init(); but unfortunately still is not working and I don't receive any error back .

Comment: You can try to `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` after calling `error_reporting(E_ALL);` just to be sure that it's displaying

Comment: added that as well. still no change :(

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$c = new dnsClass();
$zone = $c->createZone($domain);
print_r($zone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on krumo(), it's very good for debugging.